# dotnet test specify folder for packages

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, command-line-interface

For a project I'm using .NET restore for restoring the packages for the projects.

After that I'm publishing my project and running the unit tests. My YAML looks the following (simplified, only the steps below):

```
   steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: $(dotNetVersion)
    includePreviewVersions: false
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    restoreArguments: '-r win-x64'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuGet.config'
    restoreDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/packages'
    verbosityRestore: 'Quiet'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/PrintTool.csproj'
    arguments: '-r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --no-restore --source $(Pipeline.Workspace)/packages'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-restore --source $(Pipeline.Workspace)/packages --runtime win-x64'
```

I've chosen to restore the packages to a specific directory so in a later stage I can use [pipeline caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching) in combination with a [lock file](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/).

In the publish step I can refer to the folder in which my NuGet packages are restored. This works with either the parameters *--source* and *--packages*.

In the test step I can't find a way to refer to the folder in which my NuGet packages are restored *--source* and *--packages* will give the error as a unknown switch. Which I would prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this doc about [Dotnet Test Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test).

It doesn't support the argument: `--source`. So it will show the error: unknown switch.

Example:

[image]

You can add additional Dotnet Build Step and add the argument:`--no-build` to Dotnet Test Task. Then it will directly run the test based on the dll files generated by Dotnet Build Step.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: $(dotNetVersion)
    includePreviewVersions: false
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    restoreArguments: '-r win-x64'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/NuGet.config'
    restoreDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/packages'
    verbosityRestore: 'Quiet'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --source $(Pipeline.Workspace)/packages --no-restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/PrintTool.csproj'
    arguments: '-r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --no-restore --source $(Pipeline.Workspace)/packages'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-restore --no-build --runtime win-x64'
```

Comment: --source wasn't a valid option. By specifying the environment variable: NUGET_PACKAGES (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) I was able to have control over the location where the nuget packages are placed.